# Jquery Mobile:how to display a page content in a div via ajax on current window

Tags: jquery

I create a div on my page and I want to load a new "jquery mobile page" content in this div,
I bind the pagebeforechange and pagechange event  but it doesn't work.what should I do?is it impossible to show two "jqm page" on a single page at the same time?regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this with `$("#idOfDiv").load("pageUrl")`.